# Tags [navision], [microsoft-dynamics-nav] [dynamics-nav] are hard to navigate

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The tags associated with the Microsoft Dynamics software line are a mess! The Navision ones especially.

The [navision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navision) tag *could* at one point have been used for the exact software Navision--*before* it was bought out by Microsoft [sixteen years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_NAV#History). However, I would argue that just adds to the confusion, and has no additional benefit.

The [navision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navision), [dynamics-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav) and [microsoft-dynamics-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-nav) tags are surely overlapping.

Each specific version has a tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav-2009
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav-2013
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav-2015
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav-2016

Not only that, but it's inconsistent with the other Dynamics software tags. There is no Great Plains tag (for Dynamics GP). But there *IS* an [axapta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axapta) tag for, what is now, Dynamics AX.

As a result, many or all of the questions must use 5 overlapping or nearly identical tags to get an answer. Whereas, using just one or two of these tags generates far less attention and responses.

For example: [The service principal name (delegation) configuration has been set incorrectly (Ms Dynamics NAV)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50149611/7948962)

My proposal is to synonymize the [navision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navision) and [microsoft-dynamics-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-nav) tags into [dynamics-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav).

It seems prudent too for [axapta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axapta) and [dynamics-ax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-ax).

It seems relevant to leave the version(year) specific tags. This is in line with other software, which have general tags (ex: [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)), and version-specific ones (ex: [sql-server-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2017)).

Note that [microsoft-dynamics-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-crm) is *already* a synonym for [dynamics-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm). This post is recommending the same treatment for the rest of the dynamics tags. Unfortunately... the synonym for [microsoft-dynamics-ax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-ax) is [axapta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axapta) and not [dynamics-ax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-ax)...

Going to end this post here before I find more issues, and run out of space to type.