# Can we clean up the Dynamics AX tags [axapta], [d3fo], [dynamics-365-operations], [dynamics-ax7]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Due to the marketing team at Microsoft deciding on a few different names for this product over a short period of time, there are a bunch of names/tags for Dynamics AX that is leading to confusion of what to use on this site. I for one don't even know what to call it in the office let alone what to google when looking for answers.

After going through meta stack overflow and seeing this question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368175/tags-navision-microsoft-dynamics-nav-dynamics-nav-are-hard-to-navigate), I figured the same should be done for "Axapta" or whatever it is called now. Can we come up with and agree on a tag or two that could be used for AX related questions in the future?

I've even noticed that some AX related questions have been posted under the [dynamics-365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365) tag ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801319/401-connecting-to-d365-finance-and-operations-using-odata-and-net), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475355/ms-dynamics-365-for-operations-source-not-found-while-debugging) [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365+axapta)). This is just plain confusing as AX related questions being posted under a CRM tag get lost or ignored.

I'm not really sure what the perfect tag would be, but certainly something that at least distinguishes us from the other dynamics products, especially CRM, and describes the version (to distinguish from questions related to AX 2012).

Any suggestions?

[axapta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axapta) [d3fo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3fo) [dynamics-365-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365-operations) [dynamics-ax7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-ax7)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as there is not a lot of activity on this, I'm going to try answer my own question by thinking out loud about a few points.

- Because the "Dynamics 365" brand name now covers [nine different
  products](https://trials.dynamics.com/Dynamics365/Signup), it needs to be clearly differentiated from it's sibling products. While there are probably valid sales and marketing strategies
  for this, the underlying technical architecture of these products is
  sometimes vastly different. Also, the possibility of confusion between
  other products being Q&A'd on stack overflow is likely.
- Another consideration is that version
  8 is already released, and it seems that versioning will affect
  architecture and perhaps the nature of the questions asked here. (for
  example: in version 7.* some degree of overlayering is possible,
  however in version 8.* there is a hard seal in place).
- New users might not know about
  axapta or ax so including either of those terms in a tag is not ideal because they are neither future proof nor newbie friendly both of which seem to be goals of this site.

**Recommendation**
Merge [d3fo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3fo) and [dynamics-ax7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-ax7) into [dynamics-365-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365-operations). Keep [axapta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axapta) around for now for legacy purposes. Some mis-tagging may occur but can be accounted for as long as the asker adds [x++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x%2b%2b) to the post. I would also *maybe* say rename or add finance/finops to the tag [dynamics-365-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365-operations), but sometimes doing to much change could be too confusing. Adding versioning of 7.* or 8.* should be included in the question, and not the tag (for now).

Comment: It are not huge amount of questions. Anyone with 2K rep can retag those questions to their proposed target in one seating.

Comment: Yep, I've approved your latest suggested edits and cleaned up the rest myself. In the future, ping me if you need anything cleaned up.